# Sort array of string based on @number in the string content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to

```
var myArray = [
    "some text here, @8 00001#p0030",
    "some text here, @6 00001#p0030",
    "some text here, @4 00001#p0030",
    "some text here, @3 00001#p0030",
    "some text here, @1 00001#p0030",
    "some text here, @2 00001#p0030",
    "some text here, @1 00001#p0030",
    "some text here, @1 00001#p0030",
    "some text here, @8 00001#p0030",
    "some text here, @9 00001#p0030"
];
```

into something like this

```
var myArray = [
    "some text here, @1 00001#p0030",
    "some text here, @1 00001#p0030",
    "some text here, @1 00001#p0030",
    "some text here, @2 00001#p0030",
    "some text here, @3 00001#p0030",
    "some text here, @4 00001#p0030",
    "some text here, @6 00001#p0030",
    "some text here, @8 00001#p0030",
    "some text here, @8 00001#p0030",
    "some text here, @9 00001#p0030"
];
```

Is there a way to possible sort it based on @number present inside the string?

Comment: Show coding attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can try this

```js
var myArray = [
"some text here, @8 00001#p0030",
"some text here, @6 00001#p0030",
"some text here, @4 00001#p0030",
"some text here, @3 00001#p0030",
"some text here, @1 00001#p0030",
"some text here, @105 00001#p0030",
"some text here, @2 00001#p0030",
"some text here, @11 00001#p0030",
"some text here, @1 00001#p0030",
"some text here, @1 00001#p0030",
"some text here, @8 00001#p0030",
"some text here, @9 00001#p0030"
];


var sorted = myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    var sbr1=a.substr(a.indexOf("@")+1);
    var num1=parseInt(sbr1.substr(0,sbr1.indexOf(" ")));  
    var sbr2=b.substr(b.indexOf("@")+1);
    var num2=parseInt(sbr2.substr(0,sbr2.indexOf(" ")));
 
    if (num1 > num2)
        return 1;
    else if (num1 < num2)
        return -1;

    return 0;
});
console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Thanks @Çağrı! It's really a big help